# Case expression with subquery error: coud not be bound

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to use a **Case Expression** when a I have a subquery, and SQL keeps me returning

> The multi-part identifier "local1.DescricaoLotacao" could not be
>   bound.

```
    CASE WHEN (SELECT local1.[DescricaoLotacao] FROM sgp.dbo.[LOTACAO] AS [local1]
                 WHERE local1.IdLotacao = (SELECT TOP 1 [uai].[IdLotacao] FROM sgp.dbo.[UnidadeAdministrativaInterna] AS [uai]
                                            WHERE uai.[CodigoPessoal] = p.[CodigoPessoal] AND uai.[DataFinal] IS NULL ORDER BY [uai].[DataInicial] DESC)
                                           ) IS NOT NULL
        THEN local1.[DescricaoLotacao]
        ELSE ''
    END,
```

I know it's why my `local.descricaoLotacao` is out of my parentheses. But I don't know how to fix it. I thing there is another way to do this kind of select.

Comment: Put the same subquery in the `THEN` part, but without the `IS NOT NULL`. Or am I missing something.

Comment: @sami SQL returns invalid column name

Comment: @paulotarcio Post the whole query please

Comment: @SS_DBA LOL it's work.

Comment: Is `local1.[DescricaoLotacao]` only located within the `CASE WHEN` ? If so, the `THEN` part won't be able to find it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that the query will return only 1 row then instead of `CASE` use `COALESCE()`:

```
COALESCE(
  (
    SELECT local1.[DescricaoLotacao] FROM sgp.dbo.[LOTACAO] AS [local1]
    WHERE local1.IdLotacao = (
      SELECT TOP 1 [uai].[IdLotacao] 
      FROM sgp.dbo.[UnidadeAdministrativaInterna] AS [uai]
      WHERE uai.[CodigoPessoal] = p.[CodigoPessoal] AND uai.[DataFinal] IS NULL 
      ORDER BY [uai].[DataInicial] DESC
  ), 
  ''
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using `EXISTS` 
This is assuming the `local1.[DescricaoLotacao]` portion exists outside of the `CASE WHEN` section.

```
CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT local1.[DescricaoLotacao] FROM sgp.dbo.[LOTACAO] AS [local1]
                 WHERE local1.IdLotacao = (SELECT TOP 1 [uai].[IdLotacao] FROM sgp.dbo.[UnidadeAdministrativaInterna] AS [uai]
                                            WHERE uai.[CodigoPessoal] = p.[CodigoPessoal] AND uai.[DataFinal] IS NULL ORDER BY [uai].[DataInicial] DESC)
                                           ) 
        THEN local1.[DescricaoLotacao]
        ELSE ''
    END
```

Comment: If `local1.[DescricaoLotacao]` *exists outside of the CASE WHEN section* then why does the OP's code throw the error: The multi-part identifier "local1.DescricaoLotacao" could not be bound

Comment: It's not clear what line is causing the error. The `THEN` portion can not see the sub-query. Their current `CASE WHEN (SELECT ...` portion could return more than one row, causing the error.